# Reversing a string to int conversion

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, math

I have a function `PostProcess` that is fixed and cannot change. It takes an array of 6 bytes and outputs a 24-bit value.

I'm trying to work out that for a given 24-bit number what function `PreProcess` would give me the same output and input values.

For example if I set my input value to be `2^24 -1 = 16777215` then I would expect to get `16777215` on the output.

It's not clear how I would implement this functionality. I've added the code below with a test and the functionality of `PostProcess`

```
void PreProcess(unsigned int in, unsigned char out[]);
int PostProcess(unsigned char pu8Input[]);

int main()
{
    unsigned int InputVal = 16777215; // max value for 24 bits
    unsigned char PreProcessed[6] = {0};

    PreProcess(InputVal,PreProcessed);    

    unsigned int OutputVal = PostProcess(PreProcessed);

    if(InputVal == OutputVal)
        printf("True!");
    else
        printf("False");

    return 0;
}

void PreProcess(unsigned int in, unsigned char out[])
{
    //TODO
}

int PostProcess(unsigned char pu8Input[])
{
    unsigned int u32Out = 0u; 

    u32Out += (pu8Input[0] - '0') * 100000;
    u32Out += (pu8Input[1] - '0') * 10000;
    u32Out += (pu8Input[2] - '0') * 1000;
    u32Out += (pu8Input[3] - '0') * 100;
    u32Out += (pu8Input[4] - '0') * 10;
    u32Out += (pu8Input[5] - '0') * 1;
    u32Out &= 0xFFFFFF;

    return u32Out;
}
```

Comment: Are you assuming that each of the 6 bytes has a value in the range ['0','9']?

Comment: @JohnColeman those are not 6 arbitrary bytes, they're 6 numeric characters.

Comment: the values stored in pu8Input can be any 8-bit numbers. The important thing is that the output matches the given input value.. if it is possible. EDIT: i deleted my previous comment becasue it was incorrect.

Comment: Do you confirm that the maximum value that `InputVal` can have is 16777215?

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the operation

Note; with `in > 999999`, `out[0]` will be outside the '0'-'9' range.

```
void PreProcess(unsigned int in, unsigned char out[]) {
  in &= 0xFFFFFFu; // Enforce 24-bit limit.
  for (int index = 5; index > 0; index--) {
    out[index] = in%10u + '0';
    in /= 10u;
  }
  // `in` will be 0 to 167
  out[0] = in + '0;
  // With ASCII, `out[0]` will be 48 to 215
}
```

Comment: Basically the same solution I wrote. I've just been more verbose.. :)

Comment: Alright, what's the efficacy of `in % 10u` and `in / 10u` instead of just `in % 10` and `in / 10`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Same emitted code: `unsigned/int` becomes `unsigned/unsigned`.    `in % 10u` quiets a warnings about mixed sign-ness - so habit to avoid mixed sign-ness in code I write.  Of course we might get a mixed sign-ness warnings with the `+ '0'`

Comment: Gotcha -- just wanted to make sure I was thinking about it the right way, thanks!

Comment: UV for the compact, efficient and library-free implementation.

Comment: Nice simple solution, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The input integer can have the maximum value of `2^24 - 1`, the array of characters is 6 bytes long... having the possibility to change `PostProcess()` it would have been easy: 6 characters are exactly those required to store a 24 bit integer in HEX format. A character every 4 bytes; maximum value `(0x) FFFFFF`.

But `PostProcess()` implementation is fixed and it is designed as a sort of *"max-6-digits-atoi"*. So, if the input buffer's value is `{'3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'}`, then the integer `345678`.

It seems that `999999` can be printed at most, **but here comes the trick**: who bounds us to store in the char buffer only digits? We don't have any contraints (but we have to rely on **ASCII** encoding scheme).

---

### The strategy

1. Let's make sure that the lest 5 bytes of the char buffer contain the decimal representation of the input number. In this way, the `PostProcess` will convert those digits as expected. The value of those digits can be calculated as `in % 100000`
2. Being the maximum input value `2^24-1 = 16777215`, we have to represent the range `[0-167]` with the first byte of the array
3. Since the `PostProcess` will subtract `'0'` from `pu8Input[0]`, we make sure to compensate it when generating `pu8Input[0]`

---

### The code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void PreProcess(unsigned int in, unsigned char out[])
{
    if(in <= 16777215)
    {
      char aux[7];
      unsigned int auxInt = in % 100000;
      unsigned char firstchar;

      firstchar = (in / 100000) + '0';

      sprintf( aux, "%c%05u", firstchar, auxInt );

      memcpy( out, aux, 6 );
    }
}
```

Summarizing:

1. We calculate the remainder `auxInt = in % 100000`
2. We calculate the leading char as `firstchar = (in / 100000) + '0'`
3. We put them together with `sprintf`, using an auxiliary char buffer 7 bytes long (because we need room for the string terminator)
4. We `memcpy`the auxiliary char buffer to the output buffer

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, thank you. I wrote that in my editor. I must have removed it when cleaning the code.

Comment: "We don't have any contraints."   --> If encoding was [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC), I suspect `PostProcess()` would not reconstruct as desired when `in >= 1600000`.  Our trick, as is, relies on an ASCII like encoding where there is lots of room between `('9'...UCHAR_MAX]`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica though EBCDIC is a sword of damocles just here at SO. Never bothered me in "real programmer life", you are actually right. I can just surrender to it and add a disclaimer in the answer.. ;)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks! While rereading I just noticed how maybe there's too much formatting (due to lla those formulas). I wonder if there's a way to make it more readable..

Comment: I usually just bold the headings (two `"**"` on either side rather than an actual heading) and save the horizontal rules for separating original answer and subsequent edits based on further info given in the comments. What you have looks fine, but I agree it is a tad busy. You'll work out your own style after a while.

Comment: Thank you guys the answer and explanation is very helpful.